# I want different movement direction for enemies with same tag in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development

so i am creating a 2d game in unity and using a script to spawn enemies randomly from left and right sides of the screen. i have leftWall and rightWall as the boubdaries of the screen. the enemies are spawning with a prefab that has a tag "Enemy". the movement direction is initialized in the spawner script according to the side the enemy spawns in, go left if spawned right and vice versa. now what i want to when the enemy hits the wall, it should go in other direction i.e, if it hits left wall go right and if it hits right wall go left. i have the script for its movement in the enemy prefab and there i added the desired functionality with the help of chatGPT but what i got is that when one of the enemies strike the wall, the direction of every enemy is altered due to the collision event with wall tag and enemy tag. i want just the enemy that hits the wall to change its direction and not all the others. i asked chatGPT so many times but i couldnt get the answer..

here's the enemy movement script:-

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float movementSpeed = 3f;
    public Rigidbody2D enemyRB;
    //EnemySpawner enemySpawner = gaGetComponent<EnemySpawner>();
    private EnemySpawner enemySpawner;
    private float timer = 0f;
    private float enemyDestroyTime = 30f;
    private int enemyMovementDirection;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        enemySpawner = FindAnyObjectByType<EnemySpawner>();
        enemyRB = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    }

    void EnemyMoveDirection()
    {   
            enemyMovementDirection = enemySpawner.enemyMoveDirection;
            Vector2 movement = new Vector2(movementSpeed * enemyMovementDirection, enemyRB.velocity.y); // Calculate movement vector
            enemyRB.velocity = movement; // Apply movement to the rigidbody
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        EnemyMoveDirection();
        
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        if (timer >= enemyDestroyTime)
        {
            DestroyEnemy();
            enemyDestroyTime += 30f;
        }
        
        //  enemyRB.transform.position = new Vector2(movementSpeed, gameObject.transform.position.y);
    }

    
    private void DestroyEnemy()
    {
        if (enemyRB != null)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            enemySpawner.spawnCount--;
        }
    }
    

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
       // Debug.Log($"enemyRB.transform.position.x: {enemyRB.transform.position.x} && collision.collider.tag: {collision.collider.tag}");

        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("LeftWall"))
        {
            enemyMovementDirection = 1;
        }

        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("RightWall"))
        {
            enemyMovementDirection = -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused ... anything you do in `OnCollisionEnter2D` seems to be fully ignored anyway since within `Update` (every frame) you call `EnemyMoveDirection` which overwrites `enemyMovementDirection = enemySpawner.enemyMoveDirection;` ... so all your instances anyway all the time solely depend on whatever is set in `enemySpawner.enemyMoveDirection;` ...

Comment: yes that was the problem in my code and now i fixed it and it is working as intended, thank you for pointing out my mistake and helping me

Answer (score 0):

Set `enemyMovementDirection` on the Start(). Thus you won't be overriding it on every Update.

```
void Start()
{
    enemySpawner = FindAnyObjectByType<EnemySpawner>();
    enemyRB = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    enemyMovementDirection = enemySpawner.enemyMoveDirection;
}

void EnemyMoveDirection()
{   
        Vector2 movement = new Vector2(movementSpeed * enemyMovementDirection, enemyRB.velocity.y); // Calculate movement vector
        enemyRB.velocity = movement; // Apply movement to the rigidbody
    
}
```

Comment: yes i did that and now it is working fine, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

thank you guys for pointing out my mistake
turns out i put called the enemyMovement in the update method so it was not working as intented, now i put the initialization in the start method and it is working properly
here's the updated code:-

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float movementSpeed = 3f;
    public Rigidbody2D enemyRB;
    //EnemySpawner enemySpawner = gaGetComponent<EnemySpawner>();
    private EnemySpawner enemySpawner;
    private float timer = 0f;
    private float enemyDestroyTime = 30f;
    private int enemyMovementDirection;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        enemySpawner = FindAnyObjectByType<EnemySpawner>();
        enemyRB = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        enemyMovementDirection = enemySpawner.enemyMoveDirection;
    }

    void EnemyMoveDirection()
    {   
            Vector2 movement = new Vector2(movementSpeed * enemyMovementDirection, enemyRB.velocity.y); // Calculate movement vector
            enemyRB.velocity = movement; // Apply movement to the rigidbody
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        EnemyMoveDirection();
        
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        if (timer >= enemyDestroyTime)
        {
            DestroyEnemy();
            enemyDestroyTime += 30f;
        }
        
        //  enemyRB.transform.position = new Vector2(movementSpeed, gameObject.transform.position.y);
    }

    
    private void DestroyEnemy()
    {
        if (enemyRB != null)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            enemySpawner.spawnCount--;
        }
    }
    

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
       // Debug.Log($"enemyRB.transform.position.x: {enemyRB.transform.position.x} && collision.collider.tag: {collision.collider.tag}");

        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("LeftWall"))
        {
            enemyMovementDirection = 1;
        }

        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("RightWall"))
        {
            enemyMovementDirection = -1;
        }
    }
}
```